# Set minimal width of a image which may not overflow

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage which contains an header logo. This logo has two logo's in it: one with a transparent background and one with a orange background on the right. The image is like 3.000 pixels wide. I  want to resize the image to let both logo's fit in the div horizontally. So that on every device I will see the logo's and a part of the orange background (what makes the image that long.

HTML

```
<div class="logo-header"><img src="logo.png"></div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It indeed overflows nicely as I would want it, but when I use an iPhone 4 or some other small screen I am failing to get it have a minimal width.

Is this possible in CSS or is this something I should do with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.logo-header {
  background-image: url("http://bighugelabs.com/img/nbcam/ribbon_3000_bg_sh.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-header">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

if you check this image it's 3000px wide.

First of all, i recommend you optimise your image (try tinypng.com) and resize it using paint or some such (rezize before you optimize).

then use background cover and set it as a background image

Comment: The designer recommended me to use one big image instead of two others because the custom font used in both logo's, and the background on one of the images. Besides that, the proportions are needed to be followed and with two separate images I was not able to do that correctly (resizing causes the proportions to change in ratio). If it is not possible, then I will fall back on that.

Comment: @MartinBeentjes optimizising your images just reduces the file size

Comment: I know the reason for optimizing the image, I was aiming at the recommendation to use two images. But I have fixed with your solution and two mediaqueries.

Comment: @MartinBeentjes nice one :) happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to split your image in two images.

With CSS, you then insert the second image (with orange background) as background-image of `.logo-header`, aligned to the right.

Comment: I did that earlier on. The designer recommended me to not do that as that would mess up the (strict) proportions of the image. If I can not do something with just one image (maybe I'll just resize the whole image, but I'll ask) I will fallback on that idea.

Comment: I think, that you can easily resize the background image with the same proportions as the other one (to preserve the strict proportion)

Comment: you mean keep having two images and resize both an even amount?